# Unable to install openpifpaf and pycocotools with pip. ERROR: Failed building wheel for openpifpaf/pycocotools

Tags: python, macos, installation, pip, openpifpaf

Configuration:

- macOS 10.14
- Python 3.7.1

I am trying to install pycocotools and openpifpaf by issuing this command that should install `openpifpaf` and `pycocotools`:

```
pip3 install 'openpifpaf[train,test]'==0.5.2
```

as it is mentioned in my project work.

I looked at previous similar questions and tried to update setuptools and wheels, it did not help.

Basically the final message error are:

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycocotools 

ERROR: Failed building wheel for openpifpaf
```

I can provide more details on the error if necessary, I have no idea of how to fix it.

Comment: The "final" messages are useless; please post the complete error log.

Answer (score 2):

`pycocotools` is a bit special. It requires pre-installed `Cython` and `numpy` and pure pip cannot handle an order in the dependencies. You have to run `pip3 install numpy cython` before you can install openpifpaf with the `train` dependency.

I hope you find openpifpaf useful. Feel free to open an issue for this kind of question; I would have seen that earlier.

Comment: Just encountered this problem and your answer helped. What I don't get is how did you find that this was the problem? I couldn't understand it from the error msg...

Comment: Having cython installed by homebrew, I still ran into this problem. I am also puzzled by how you found this, but appreciate the insight greatly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error for when I tried `pip install pycocotools` to my virtual environment `venv`. Installing pycocotools has other package dependencies - I'm not sure which exactly  but it's among [these here](https://github.com/triple-tam/CenterPoint/blob/master/requirements.txt) which are installed in `venv`. Probably just `numpy` and `cython` are necessary, but I haven't tested that.

Make these dependencies findable by adding `venv` to the `PYTHONPATH` in `~./bash_profile`:

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:path/to/venv"
```